# Draw Line chart with openpyxl - Axis/drawing issue

Tags: python, excel, graph, openpyxl

I'm having problems getting the LineChart() feature of Openpyxl to draw the chart in the way that I'd like it.

I've been using the documentation on [the official page](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/line.html), but I get [image: This result in Excel].

This is the desired result (ignore the colour/formatting, just need to get the data points correct, then I can style it):

[image]

I've tried to rearrange the data into vertical slices in the masterList list in the same way they demonstrate in the documentation, but I don't understand how the graph actually uses the data between the

```
for i in masterList:
    #print ("Appending ", i, "to the sheet")
    sheet.append(i)
```

section, and the below line:

```
data = Reference(sheet, min_col = 4, min_row = 7, max_col = currentCell, max_row = 28)
```

Whole function below. version = "v1.9", currentCell = number of dates we have data for, and sheet is the current active worksheet in the workbook.

```
def drawChart(self, sheet, currentCell, version):
    print ("CurrentCell = ", currentCell)
    ### Get the chart data
    dateData, versionData, versionXABData = ([] for i in range(3)) #Make 3 lists 
    for i in range(currentCell):
        temp = sheet.cell(row = 7, column = 4+i).value
        if not temp: 
            temp = 0
            dateData.append(temp)
        else: dateData.append(temp) #Put the dates in a list

    for i in range(currentCell):
        temp = sheet.cell(row = 28, column = 4+i).value
        if not temp: 
            temp = 0
            versionData.append(temp)
        else: versionData.append(temp) #Put the version Totals in another

    for i in range(currentCell):
        temp = sheet.cell(row = 27, column = 4+i).value
        if not temp: 
            temp = 0
            versionXABData.append(temp)
        else: versionXABData.append(temp) #Put the version XAB bugs in another

    print ("Dates are: ", dateData, '\n', "VersionData is: ",versionData, '\n', "Version XAB is: ", versionXABData, '\n')

    masterList = [list() for i in range(currentCell)] #Make a list containing the total number of empty lists for each day we have data for
    masterList[0].append("Date")
    masterList[0].append("Total "+ version +" Bugs")
    masterList[0].append("Total "+ version +" XAB Bugs")
    print (masterList[0])


    for i in range(1, currentCell):
        #print (" Length of dataData = ", len(dateData), '\n', "Length of versionData = ", len(versionData), '\n', "Length of versionXABData = ", len(versionXABData), '\n',"i = ", i)
        masterList[i].append(dateData[i])
        masterList[i].append(versionData[i])
        masterList[i].append(versionXABData[i])

    for i in masterList:
        #print ("Appending ", i, "to the sheet")
        sheet.append(i)

    chart1 = LineChart()
    chart1.title = "DoT Bug Burndown"
    chart1.style = 13
    chart1.y_axis.title = "No of Bugs"
    chart1.x_axis.title = "Date"
    chart1.width = 30
    chart1.height = 20

    data = Reference(sheet, min_col = 4, min_row = 7, max_col = currentCell, max_row = 28)
    chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    sheet.add_chart(chart1, "K31")
```

Comment: *draw the chart in the way that I'd like it.* **<--** You should probably consider illustrating the desired output, otherwise, it's anybody's guess as to what you actually expect the output to look like...

Comment: You may also need to change the `PlotBy` argument (not sure what it's called in openpyxl) because it *looks* like you want to plot by the dates, but the screenshot displays that the *series* are the dates.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! 

Added a screenshot to show the desired result. 

Will investigate the PlotBy argument now.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by writing the new data to a new sheet after reading it.

The way it was originally meant that it wasn't using the correct axis orientation, so the revised code below appends the content of the masterList to a new sheet of the workbook, in data columns (as opposed to rows), as is shown in the LineChart example of the supporting documentation.

```
def drawChart(self, sheet, sheet2, currentCell, version):
    print ("CurrentCell = ", currentCell)
    ### Get the chart data
    dateData, versionData, versionXABData = ([] for i in range(3)) #Make 3 lists 
    for i in range(currentCell):
        temp1 = sheet.cell(row = 7, column = 4+i).value
        temp2 = str(temp1)
        temp3 = temp2[:10]
        if not temp1: 
            temp2 = 0
            dateData.append(temp3)
        else: dateData.append(temp3) #Put the dates in a list

    for i in range(currentCell):
        temp = sheet.cell(row = 28, column = 4+i).value
        if not temp: 
            temp = 0
            versionData.append(temp)
        else: versionData.append(temp) #Put the version Totals in another

    for i in range(currentCell):
        temp = sheet.cell(row = 27, column = 4+i).value
        if not temp: 
            temp = 0
            versionXABData.append(temp)
        else: versionXABData.append(temp) #Put the version XAB bugs in another

    print ("Dates are: ", dateData, '\n', "VersionData is: ",versionData, '\n', "Version XAB is: ", versionXABData, '\n')

    masterList = [list() for i in range(currentCell)] #Make a list containing the total number of empty lists for each day we have data for
    masterList[0].append("Date")
    masterList[0].append("Total "+ version +" Bugs")
    masterList[0].append("Total "+ version +" XAB Bugs")

    print ("MasterList = ", masterList[0])

    for i in range(1, currentCell):
        #print (" Length of dataData = ", len(dateData), '\n', "Length of versionData = ", len(versionData), '\n', "Length of versionXABData = ", len(versionXABData), '\n',"i = ", i)
        masterList[i].append(dateData[i])
        masterList[i].append(versionData[i])
        masterList[i].append(versionXABData[i])




    for i in masterList:
        print ("Appending ", i, "to the sheet")
        sheet2.append(i)

    chart1 = LineChart()
    chart1.title = version + " Bug Burndown"
    chart1.style = 2

    chart1.y_axis.title = "No of Bugs"
    chart1.width = 30
    chart1.height = 20




    data = Reference(sheet2, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=36)
    chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

    #s = Series(y, xvalues = x)

    dates = Reference(sheet2, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=36)
    chart1.set_categories(dates)

    chart1.legend.position = 'b'

    s1 = chart1.series[0]
    s2 = chart1.series[1]
    s1.graphicalProperties.line.width = 50000
    s2.graphicalProperties.line.width = 50000
```